# Select XML Nodes and Pass to ListView Problem

Tags: c#, xml

As mentioned earlier this is nonsense.

I made a function for listview's refresh. and I get IEnumerable to set Listview.Itemsource
It works, but It doesn't work when I add 'MessageBox.Show' in the function.

```
public IEnumerable<WorkTask> GetAllTasks(string business_title, string xml = BasicPath)
        {
            var accountDataDoc = new XmlDocument();
            accountDataDoc.Load(xml);
            foreach (XmlNode task in accountDataDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Task"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("ERROR");
                yield return new WorkTask(
                    task.SelectSingleNode("Title").InnerText,
                    task.SelectSingleNode("Describe").InnerText,
                    task.SelectSingleNode("Priority").InnerText
                );
            }
        }
```

It works in itself function.

but I call this function elsewhere, sure to check that it is null It error 'NullExpection'

```
public void RefreshTaskListView(){
            IEnumerable<WorkTask> tasks = BusinessManager.GetAllTasks(BusinessName);
            if (tasks == null)
                return;

            TaskListView.ItemsSource = tasks;
}
```

ADDing 'MessageBox.Show' in GetAlltask -> Error in 'TaskListView.ItemSource = tasks' NULLEX
but
Excepting 'MessageBox.Show' in GetAlltask -> No error. it works

I don't know why does it is.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TRxKs.png)

Comment: Adding the line MessageBox should not cause a null exception.  So something else must be causing the issue.  I would first try a CLEAN Build and try again. If you still get the error then you must be getting an exception some place else in the code.  You will need to isolate where the error is coming by stepping through code and adding break points.  Often the Net library is you do not have exception handlers (try/catch) will give erroneous exceptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely, that MessageBox uses "unsafe" blocks of code.

If you look to the description of the yield keyword it says:

> You can't include a yield return or yield break statement in:
>
> Lambda expressions and anonymous methods.
>
> **Methods that contain unsafe blocks**. For more information, see unsafe.

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield

Comment: Although I racked my brain It didn't solve But Your answer helped me and you also let me learn about unsafe of c# It was very useful information for me.Thank you Thomas. my english is the worst however you understood my expression I think you are genius haha .. Thank you for your answer)